# Git handle multiple remotes with different content

Tags: git, git-remote

In order to base multiple projects on a base functionality we plan to have a base repository containing some scaffolding / common functionality code.

A new project is created basing on this skeleton. It will have its own remote where application changes are put. In order to be able to update the project if something in the common functionality changes the remote to the "scaffold" repository should be kept. The project itself has then two remotes (one "origin" for the project itself and one "scaffold" for the common functionality).

So far the best way to update from "scaffold" seems to merge the changes. But there might be conflicts as there are basically different contents in the two remotes. The tool managing the remotes is Gerrit.

The question is how to best handle a requirement like this.

Comment: git submodule as they are separate projects

Comment: Maybe it is a bit unclear: The scaffold contains files that could be changed in the concrete application but should stay merge-able (also if a conflict might be the result).